# How to eliminate the warnings: mockbuild does not exist

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

I was building a package from SRPM on Fedora:

```
$ rpmbuild --rebuild *.src.rpm

...
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
...
```

The package was built but there were many such `mockbuild does not exist` warnings. There doesn't seem to be such an account on my system, even though I have package `mock` installed. Are there any other packages I'm missing? Is this a fault on the package or my system? How to eliminate these warnings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't, and they don't do anything anyways. They are an artifact of the package having been built in the [Fedora buildsystem](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Koji).

Comment: So where can I find the details about where these artifacts come from and why they must exist? The koji page doesn't mention user/group `mockbuild`, and I'm building on my machine not on koji. I'm not really good at remembering which warnings are harmful and which are false alarms so I prefer they get fixed somehow.

Comment: Even SRPMs must be built. And they are being built as `mockbuild`.

Comment: My understanding is that you can build with any user/group so I don't think it should warn me with a specific one. If rpmbuild must use user/group `mockbuild` to build SRPM, then I can add this user/group. But it's better to understand what's happening before modifying the system.

Comment: Files in a RPM are owned by a specific user and group. In a SRPM from Fedora's buildsystem they are owned by `mockbuild`. Adding a local user called `mockbuild` won't help, since normal users can't chown files regardless.

Comment: I'd like to clarify this a bit. SRPM contains source code, whose owner doesn't matter, as long as the builder can read the files. RPM contains binary files, but those files are built on MY machine, where there isn't a `mockbuild` user. Why would I expect the built binary files to be owned by a non-existent user?

Comment: I don't understand why you would, and I don't understand what that question is doing here. If you're asking "Why do files in a SRPM have an owner?", the answer is that SRPMs are still RPMs, they just happen to contain source instead of built binaries.

Comment: No, I don't care about SRPM file owners. My question is actually very simple: I don't have user/group `mockbuild` on my machine and I don't want packages built on my machine to be bothered with those warnings. So I'd like to understand why rpmbuild would spit out those warnings. Well, the comments have grown very long so I probably wait for a while.

Comment: It spits out those warnings *because* those are the SRPM file owners.

Comment: All right I got your point. My research shows that downloaded RPMs have  file owners `root` but SRPMs have `mockbuild`. How difficult is it to fix the owner that won't be available on most users system before shipping out those SRPMs...

Comment: Just unpack them and then repack them with the username that will eventually unpack them.

Answer (score 2):

Installing **mock** is the way to go, if you are interested in making the same package as Fedora's (as opposed to just creating an rpm).  When installing that, the package creates a `mock` user which happens to partially fix the problem. According to the Fedora wiki page [*Using Mock to test package builds*](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Using_Mock_to_test_package_builds#Using_Mock_outside_your_git_sandbox), you should add *yourself* to the `mock` group:

> Add your user name to the mock group
>
> `sudo usermod -a -G mock` *myusername*

Doing that fixed the warnings which I got in a rebuild of Fedora's ncurses source-packages.  Depending on the version of ***[mock](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock)*** (and the packages built using it), there may be a `mockbuild` account referenced in the source-rpms:

> commit c33ccca2d36250e9d9fb7dec85fa72c311d43adb
> Author: Miroslav Suchý 
> Date:   Thu Nov 13 14:59:00 2014 +0100
>
> ```
> run --shell as root with --new-chroot
>
> Until now --new-chroot run --shell as 'mockbuild' user. This is
> regression from --old-chroot, where it was run as root user.
> ```

Further reading:

- [build rpm packages such as Redhat/Fedora](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2010-November/145510.html):

> On 11/13/2010 18:15, Christopher Stolzenberg wrote:
>
> > `yum install mock`
> > `useradd mockbuild`
> > `usermod -G mock mockbuild`
>
> Unless you want to ``su'' to a dedicated mockbuild account every time
> you want to build you should add your usual account to the mock group
> instead.
>
> > `mock rebuild -r epel-6-x86_64 /home/mockbuild/kernel 2.6.32-71.7.1.el6.src.rpm`
>
> Mock typically grabs packages from CentOS, so until CentOS 6 is out
> you're going to have to build using RHEL 6.

- [Building RPMS](https://srobb.net/rpmbuild.html):

> The Fedora project's [page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_GNU_Hello_RPM_package) says to add your user to mock. You can skip this, but to avoid errors later (when installing srpms), add a mockbuild user. The *mockbuild* user doesn't need a password.
>
> `sudo useradd mockbuild`

Comment: Doing that fixed the warning on the group mock, but still get> warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root<  I'm working on gcc.src.

Comment: one might consider `sudo usermod -a -G mock $( whoami )`

Comment: thanks for this, I was able to backport some Fedora packages for CentOS Stream 9 with ease, much appreciated.